# Docker -v (volume mount) equivalent in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am looking for a kubernetes equivalent of `docker -v` for mounting the volumes in gcloud.

I am trying to run my container using google-container-engine which uses kubectl to manage clusters. In the kubectl run command I could not fund any provision for mounting the volumes.

```
 kubectl run foo --image=gcr.io/project_id/myimage --port 8080
```

I checkout their [official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/docker-cli-to-kubectl/#docker-run) but could not find any clue whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

As at the moment, It's not possible to mount a persistent Volume in a container by using imperative ways or using generators command (run, expose).Therefore, You could use declarative way to get it done.

Kubernetes provides 2 abstractions for storage in a cluster which are persistent volume claim (PVC) and persistent volume (PV). Moreover, you can use storage class to provide Persistent volume (PV) in a dynamic way.

[persistent-volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/).

[storage-classes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/)

When you write a manifest file for deployment you need to use a volume claim field to access PVC as well as you will write a PVC to claim PV.

Comment: This answer just feels too vague to me, I feel like I'm barely closer to understanding how k8s permits volumes with `kubectl run` than before I read it. Almost every term you mention (manifest, Operator etc.) would be foreign to someone new to k8s

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have updated the answer. I am also new to k8s as well. However, I will try to research some k8s vocabulary on their official site  If I want to get familiar with these terms.

Comment: I think what is really missing is how this can be used by `kubectl run` specifically

Comment: `run ` operations is called generator in K8s. At the moment, Kubernetes does not support this functionality.